# Simple password login don't work. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, passwords

I try to create a loging form. In that I add a const password which I can login. And after a login I want to able to show a none displayed div. But this don't work.

```js
function check() {
```

```css
#header,
#panel {
  padding: 5px;
```

```html
<form id="logIn">
  <input type="password" id="passw" name="passw">
```

Comment: Is this just a practice project? I ask as it's literally the least secure method of password protection. Also, you don't appear to have asked a question, just stated a list of requirements. Do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, this is just a practice project. 
Those requrements are just helping tasks, someone who does not really understand my problem.
I tried to break it as I would have started.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting error because your using `#`  when getting elements by id.
I think this will fix your error.
But you'r method of login is highly vulnerable. It's not recommend to test your plain password. Make it encrypted/hashed with some sort of algorithm `(not of your own)`

```
 function check() {
    const password = "2222";        
    const pass = document.getElementById("passowrd").value;
    if (password == "2222") {
    document.write('your are logged in');

  } else {
    alert("Error Password ");
  }
}
```

Comment: It is just a practice. But still not accept a password and not show the div element.